# Chronometer using C signals

Tags: c, signals

I have to do a Chronometer by using C signals. The idea is the following:

- Use SIGUSR1: when the child gets SIGUSR1 signal it will pause his chronometre and show the current state. (for example time: 5s)
- Use SIGUSR2: when the child gets SIGUSR2 signal it will reset his chronometre (by putting it's time to 0)

So on the parent will be a kind of interface with 2 options (that I have just told). The child will be runing attending to parent's signals.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h> 

void stop_and_continue(int x);
void reset(int x);


int state;   //If chrometre is stop (0) or runing (1)
int pid_child;
int time;

int main(void){

int pid;
int option;
system("clear");
pid = fork();

if( pid == 0){  //child (chronometre)
    signal(SIGUSR1, stop_and_continue);
    signal(SIGUSR2, reset);
    time = 0;
    state = 0;   //Originally the chronometre is stop
    pid_child = getpid();   //store child's pid on global to use it on signal functions
    pause();   //Wait till parent say to start for the first time
    while(1){
        sleep(1);   //Wait 1 second to make it "real"
        time++;
    }       
}else{   //Parent
    printf("1 - Stop - Continue\n");
    printf("2 - Reset\n");
    printf("0 - Exit\n");
    printf("Select one option:\n");
    do{
        scanf("%d",&option);
        if(option == 1){
            kill(pid,SIGUSR1);
        }else if(option == 2){
            kill(pid,SIGUSR2);
        }
    }while(option!=0);
    kill(pid,SIGKILL);
    wait(NULL);  //Wait till child finish to avoid zombis
}
return 0;
}

void reset(int x){
time = 0;
}

void stop_and_continue(int x){
if(state == 1){
    state = 0;
    kill(pid_child,SIGSTOP);
}else{
    state = 1;
    kill(pid_child,SIGCONT);
}
```

}

Comment: Kid and father? You mean child and parent?

Comment: Yes, sorry I'm spanish and I have try to traduce it fastly, I will edit it

Comment: I`m not sure, if process is able to handle user-signals after SIGSTOP. Are you sure, this start/stop works?

Comment: The reset function works perfectly but when I try tu use the start/stop function it doesnt work the third time, I mean when it's suppose to restart after stop. I dont know any other way to pause it till SIGCONT

Comment: @fingerlabs may be it is better to add `if (state) time++;` instead of starting/stopping process by signal SIGSTOP. I suspect, process hangs forever.

Comment: I have found a tricky solution: use a conditional expresion (state == 1) in order to do timer++ and sleep(1) so the start/stop function only will have to change state var. But I dont think that will be the profesor ask for...

Comment: Just wath you said jajaja

Answer (score 0):

Do not send SIGSTOP and SIGCONT to yourself. SIGSTOP will HALT your-self, until you receive a SIGCONT from somewhere else. Instead, inside your while look, add to check for state:

```
while(1){
    sleep(1);   //Wait 1 second to make it "real"
    if (state) {  
        time++;
    }
}
```

.

```
void stop_and_continue(int x){
    state = !state;
}
```